# How to give an SPGroup permissions for an SPItem?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, permissions, sharepoint-2010

I tried to find a simple example how to give a certain Sharepoint group X, a permission level Y, for list item Z - but can't find example code.

The shortest code I could come up with for assigning a specific **user** permissions ("Reader" in this case) for the item is the following:

```
SPRoleDefinition spRole = spWeb.RoleDefinitions["Reader"];    
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment= new SPRoleAssignment("//myDomain/myUser",
                                                      "none@example.org",
                                                      "Name", "Notes");    
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spRole);

SPListItem listItem = spWeb.GetListItem("http://<URL to item somewhere on the Site>");
listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
listItem.RoleAssegnments.Add(roleAssignment);
listItem.Update();
```

I know that `SPRoleAssignment.Add` can also take an `SPPrincipal` which in turn [is a group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spprincipal.aspx) - I just don't know how do write it.

Please give me some example code for how to add an existing Sharepoint group (e.g. "MyGroup") with the "Reader" permission level to my item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it was rather easy - instead of the `SPRoleAssignment("user","name"...)` I could just add an `SPGroup` to the role assignment and it worked! Full code following:

```
//note: using SiteGroups is "safer",
//because also groups which don't yet have any permissions are included
SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.SiteGroups["MyGroup"];
SPRoleDefinition spRole = spWeb.RoleDefinitions["Read"]; 

SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment= new SPRoleAssignment(spGroup);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spRole);

SPListItem listItem = spWeb.GetListItem("http://<URL to item somewhere on the Site>");
listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
listItem.Update();
```

Comment: I am getting null values in the roleAssignment when I give spgroup in constructor. What to do for that? The group is found but not working.

Comment: One Typo. It's RoleAssignments not RoleAssegnments