# SharePoint RoleAssignment Won't Add

Tags: .net, vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to manipulate SPListItem permissions on folders in a document library but I can't seem to add any new permissions, though removing security inheritance works beautifully.

I've done my best to create a slimmed down version of the code for testing purposes.  The function GetListItem returns the SPListItem we are working with based on the URL. The `item.BreakRoleInheritance(False)` works great and I've verified properly breaks inheritance and clears out any permissions, I've also tried it with the True flag and verified that all original permissions are copied from the parent.

The code below throws no exceptions and as far as I can tell appears to work fine, until I check the actual permissions on the folder in my document library and see that "Viewers" is not listed.

**Code:**

```
    Dim item As SPListItem = GetListItem(URL)

    If item Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim spGrp = SharePointWeb.SiteGroups("Viewers")
    Dim spRole As SPRoleDefinition = SharePointWeb.RoleDefinitions("Read")

    Dim roleAssignment As New SPRoleAssignment(spGrp)
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spRole)

    SharePointWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True

    item.BreakRoleInheritance(False)
    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment)
    item.Update()

    SharePointWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = False
```

I have tried wrapping this code in a call to `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` but it didn't make any difference.  The creation of my SPSite/SPWeb objects is wrapped in a call to `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` and I have other code that runs which finds/deletes/updates attributes on folders/etc... with this existing code; just permissions don't want to work.

References:
 - http://moldenco.blogspot.com/2007/05/spsecurityrunwithelevatedprivileges-to.html
 - [How to give an SPGroup permissions for an SPItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934168/how-to-give-an-spgroup-permissions-for-an-spitem)
 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/10/05/sharepoint-roles-assignments.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through researching the issue and trying a veriety of different methods I happened across an exception, "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" which occured in SPWebEnsureSPControl.

I did some googling and found this forum post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/32869ac6-4f47-46b8-accf-f56966ac9581 which lead me to modify my code.  I made `System.Web.HttpContext.Current = Nothing` the first line of code after calling `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` and everything started working.

So my code looks something like (using an anonomous delegate):

```
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(Sub()
                                             System.Web.HttpContext.Current = Nothing
                                             ........
                                         End Sub)
```

From what I read `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` still has connections to your non-elevated account and by setting it to null it gets rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this. If you still have trouble with these methods because of permissions try not to use elevated priviliges but impersonation. I posted a method for this below the permission methods:

```
 public static void SetPermissions(SPListItem item, IEnumerable<SPPrincipal> principals)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPPrincipal principal in principals)
                    {
                        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions[Constants.SiteCollection.SecurityTypeNames.contribute];
                        SetPermissions(item, principal, roleDefinition);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SPException exc)
            {
                //catch exception
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// setpermissions method for one group
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <param name="principal"></param>
        /// <param name="roleType"></param>
        public static void SetPermissions(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal principal)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions[Constants.SiteCollection.SecurityTypeNames.contribute];
                SetPermissions(item, principal, roleDefinition);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// permission setting method used by previous two setpermissions method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <param name="principal"></param>
        /// <param name="roleDefinition"></param>
        public static void SetPermissions(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal principal, SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition)
        {

            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
                roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

                item.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }

        }
```

impersonation methods:

```
public static SPWeb GetImpersonatedWeb(SPSite impSite, string impWebUrl)
        {
        ILogger logger = SharePointServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<ILogger>();

        try
        {
            SPUserToken systoken = impSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(impSite.Url, systoken))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[GetServerRelUrlFromFullUrl(impWebUrl)];
                return web;
            }
        }
        catch (SPException exc)
        {
            //catch exception
        }
    }

    public static SPSite GetImpersonatedSite()
    {
        try
        {
            SPSite impSite = SPContext.Current.Site;

            SPUserToken systoken = impSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
            SPSite site = new SPSite(impSite.Url, systoken);
            return site;
        }
        catch (SPException exc)
        {
            //catch exception
        }
    }

public static string GetServerRelUrlFromFullUrl(string url)
        {
        int index = url.IndexOf("//");
        if ((index < 0) || (index == (url.Length - 2)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        int startIndex = url.IndexOf('/', index + 2);
        if (startIndex < 0)
        {
            return "/";
        }
        string str = url.Substring(startIndex);
        if (str.IndexOf("?") >= 0)
            str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("?"));

        if (str.IndexOf(".aspx") > 0)
            str = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("/"));

        if ((str.Length > 1) && (str[str.Length - 1] == '/'))
        {
            return str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
        }
        return str;
    }
```