# How to assign my custom permission level to my TestGroup?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have created one group Name: TestGroup 
and one permission level Name: Custompermisionlevel

How can I assign the permission level(Custompermisionlevel) to my group programmatically?

I'm using this code:

```
public void SetPermissionsToGroup()
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite("http://sp2010:8888"))
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //Get group and group roles
                var group = web.SiteGroups["TestGroup"];
                var roles = new SPRoleAssignment(group);                   

                //Add another role
                roles.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Custompermisionlevel));
                roles.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not getting my Custompermisionlevel in SPRoleType. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

getting this error:Cannot update a permission level assignment that is not part of a permission level assignment collection.

Comment: Is this SharePoint?  
If so you'll have better luck tagging it as such and/or asking over at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934168/how-to-give-an-spgroup-permissions-for-an-spitem) has some good code.  What you need to do is get a reference to the custom permission level by referencing the specific `SPRoleDefinition` on the `SPWeb`.

Here is some sample code that assigns a permission level "**My Test Level**" to an SPList for a specified SPUser.

```
SPWeb currentWeb = topSite.RootWeb;
SPList testList = currentWeb.Lists["ListName"];
SPUser currentUser = currentWeb.SiteUsers["domain\\userName"];
SPRoleAssignment customRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(currentUser);

SPRoleDefinition customRoleDefinition = currentWeb.RoleDefinitions["My Test Level"];
customRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(customRoleDefinition);

testList.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
testList.RoleAssignments.Add(customRoleAssignment);
testList.Update();
```